# C++ which if/else is faster

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have seen two types of if/else, which one is faster?

```
if(a==b) cout<<"a";
else cout<<"b";
```

OR

```
a==b ? cout<<"a" : cout<<"b";
```

Comment: If you care you have to measure.

Comment: Why should one be faster then the other?

Comment: Don't worry about this at all. You will have to worry about a lot of other things when writing an application that solves some real world problems.

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.... don't do it.

Comment: I say if it takes 1 billionth of a second or even 20 billionths of a second more how would you even know? The `cout` is going to take much longer.

Comment: How about `std::cout << (a == b)["ba"];` ? :-)

Comment: Speed up your algorithms, use efficient data structures, and not concern yourself with rinky-dink `if` statements.

Comment: The truth is in the assembly language output.  Most processors require at least 2 instructions for a conditional expression:  compare and branch.  Most processors don't like branch instructions because they may cause a reload of the instruction cache.  Regardless, generate the assembly language for each example and compare them.  Reduce branching if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary conditional is an abuse since it's a mere coincidence that `decltype(cout<<"a")` is a type that can be used in a ternary conditional:

```
cout << (a == b ? "a" : "b");
```

would be more palatable, and possibly more tractable than the `if`, `else`, which you should otherwise prefer for its clarity.

And trust your compiler to make the optimisations. checking the output assembly if you have any suspicions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Did I mess up my operator precedence?!

Comment: Apparently so. :P

Answer (score 2):

The performance of either would never be catastrophic for your program.

It all comes down to Code readability.

The tertiary operator has its limitation of only one statement either true or false.